# Suppressing all R.java checks in Android Studio inspection

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, lint

*Using Android Studio version 4.0.*

I'm trying to clean up all of the inspection errors, But I can't find how to get rid of the checks that are being made on the R.java file.

[image]

I did try to **Exclude** it from the scope of the check, but then the inspection gets stuck because it relies on it for references.

How do I remove it than?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was [fixed in IntelliJ 13.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117724) ([Android Studio 0.5.0](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio050released))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio incorrectly does inspections on generated code in the `build` folder, which is the behavior you're seeing. This was filed as this bug against Android Studio: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64651 which you can read and see some extended commentary. It's actually a bug in the underlying IntelliJ base, not anything specific to Android Studio. The best place to track it seems to be this bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119399

Comment: This was [fixed in IntelliJ 13.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117724) ([Android Studio 0.5.0](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio050released))